# How to move smoothly between points from server?

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, client-server, game-physics

I have Node.js server and Unity client. Server side sends new player coordinates every 40-50 milliseconds (depends on the load), but its too much for moving without lags.

My wrong version pseudocode:

```
    GameObject player;

    serverListener += TakeCoordFromServer;

    Vector3 oldCoord = Vector.zero;
    Vector3 newCoord = Vector.zero;

    float deltaServerTime = 0.0f;
    float estimatedSpeedMove = 0.0f;
    float lastTime = 0.0f;
    Vector3 lastPosition = Vector.zero;

    void TakeCoordFromServer(Vector3 _newCoord) //every 40-50 ms
    {
        this.oldCoord = this.newCoord;
        this.newCoord = _newCoord;

        this.lastPosition = this.player.transform.position;

        this.deltaServerTime = Time.time - this.lastTime;
        this.lastTime = Time.time;
        this.estimatedSpeedMove = Vector3.Distance(this.lastPosition, this.NewPosition.position) / deltaServerTime;
    }


    Update () {
        this.player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.lastPosition, this.newCoord, Time.deltaTime * estimatedSpeedMove);
    }
```

Please help me to move player without trembles

Comment: most games continue items on their last known trajectory and speed in case of missed message.. long as you're using udp this can work

Comment: @BugFinder i use tcp, if I use speed from the server - I'll get the out of sync positions, because packets can delayed

Comment: If the game is multiplayer, you should consider switch over to UDP; it's better suited for online games (https://gafferongames.com/post/udp_vs_tcp/).  To fix your issue, the technique @BugFinder mentioned is called "Dead Reckoning" and is a very common solution for dealing with latency (https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131638/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php).